# Headless Raspberry Pi won't cold boot without monitor - with monitor OK

Tags: raspbian, boot, headless

My old 256M Raspberry Pi shows odd headless boot behaviour it will not boot headless (SD green access briefly, but no ethernet lights). Official Raspian SD from ele14 that has been updated.

- Cold boot, no monitor, no boot, no ethernet lights.
- If I add a monitor thru hdmi2vga converter, cold boot OK, ethernet OK.
- If I remove the monitor and 'sudo reboot' (without disconnecting power) it boots OK, ethernet OK.
- If I power off and on with no monitor it does not boot (SD access
  blinks a few times) & no ethernet lights. Even if I wait.

/var/log/syslog seems not to have anything useful - like nothing being logged during failed boots.

Answer (score 1):

From d586's solution:

1. 90% of all problems are power supply - swapping the official PSU
   with a 2A Nexus 7 seemed to solve the problem
2. Permanent fix - blew away the installed Raspian and installed NOOBS_v1_3 then Raspian, seems to boot on any PSU now.